# pointer initializing in C++!

Tags: c++, pointers

Why this code works? It should given an error.

```
int* p;
*p=34;
cout<<*p<<endl;
```

int* p should only allocate memory for pointer itself.The value of the pointer will be some memory address, but the memory at that address is not yet allocated.

Comment: Do you think that everyone who makes a mistake on their taxes goes to jail?

Comment: So exactly what value does `p` have in this instance, and what does the system you're running this do to writes to specifically that address? A pointer, generally, contains a memory address, and doing `*p = 34;` (are you a Kevin Schwantz fan?) is writing to the address in `p` - since it's uninitialized, the C++ standard says it's unspecified what it has. You also haven't told us WHAT system you are running this on - in an old DOS system for example, your program can write to the entire accessible memory without anything going wrong directly from the write (obviously other things can go wrong)

Comment: @tejal567: This code does not "work". This code produces *undefined behavior* for reasons you correctly identified yourself.

Comment: Even the most stupid compiler can optimize `*p=34; cout<<*p<<endl;` into `cout<<34<<endl`, and suddenly it "works". See [constant propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding#Constant_propagation)

Answer (score 4):

In C++, pointers are not initialized to NULL by default. The program will show undefined behaviour each time you run it, and may give a segmentation fault at times.

Comment: "Hence"? Even if pointer were initialized to null by default (static ones are actually), the code would still produce undefined behavior.

Answer (score -2):

When you write  int *p = new int; the address pointed by *p which gets a size of "int" allocated. 
And when you write *p=34 the address gets a value of 34;

You can creare a pointer without "new"  just like a variable (a pointing variable). Using "new" is  simply a manual way to allocate memory. Our compilers are  smart enough.  But remember its not good practice. Some compiles might throw errors.  Always use "new"  to avoid errors and also delete your allocations when you're done.

Comment: The question is asking why the program works without doing *p=new int, without giving an error.